# ng-click not working in a popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have created a button inside a popover but the ng-click function is not being trigged.

Here is my button:

```
   <div class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <button 
          href="#" 
          data-toggle="popover" 
          data-placement="bottom" 
          data-content="<button ng-click='logout()' class='pop'><p>Sign out</p></button>"
          data-html="true">
          <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And here is my js:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
   });
```

what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Post your complete HTML code. Where is your `ng-controller`?

Comment: This approach is totally wrong. While `.popover()` is a bootstrap function based on jQuery your template `data-content` never gets compiled by AngularJS. Please use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to run bootstrap + AngularJS in a nice way.

Comment: You're trying to pass an angular template into a third party component (i.e. a raw Bootstrap Popover). You can't do this, specifically down to timing, the angular template won't be compiled by the time the bootstrap component is generated. Consider using [UI Bootstrap Popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover) instead and you should be able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Added angular ui and evething works the same: the box shows up, it has link, I see the function when I inspect it but nothing happens after clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$(".pop-over-class").popover({
      'placement': 'bottom',
      'trigger': 'click',
      'html': true,
      'container': 'body',
      'content': function() {
           return $compile($(".pop-over-class").html())(scope);
      }
}
```

As you need to compile the content returned to the popover.